# Is a linear map that preserves boundedness bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis

If I have any linear map $T: X \to Y$ then one clearly has: if $T$ is bounded , then $T$ preserves boundedness, i.e.: $$\exists C>0: \forall x\in X: \lVert Tx\rVert \leq C \lVert x \rVert\\ \implies \\ \forall X'\subseteq X: \text{if $X'$ is bounded, than T(X) is bounded}$$
I want to know if the converse also holds.

Comment: What have you tried? Try writing out the converse, putting down some examples, and seeing if you can generalise to either prove or disprove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $X'=\{x:\|x\| \leq 1\}$. You get a constant $C$ such that  $\|Tx\| \leq C$ whenever $\|x\| \leq 1$. Now take any $x \neq 0$ and apply this to $\frac x {\|x\|}$. Can you complete the proof now?.

Answer (score 0):

By definition (one of its three equivalent formulations) linear map is bounded if and only if the image of the unit ball is bounded, so yes.

Comment: Ok, but how do I prove _that_?

Comment: EDIT: ok, now I got it. I added the proof to your answer, because I needed it to see that this is true.